# ansible-pull with --tags flag doesn't work

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that includes a file containing this:

```
- name: debug tags
  debug: 
    msg: debug tags
  tags: 
    - debugtags
```

When I run the following command, I would expect that only this play be executed. Instead, no play is executed.  This is in a docker container on my linux desktop, so it needs to go out and get the playbook. I'm sure that the play is in the playbook.  The command (edited a bit for security)

```
/usr/bin/ansible-pull -C dockervm -d /usr/local/ansible -U git@github.com:xxxxx-config-usr_local_ansible.git -i localhost, -e small=yes vagrant=True ServerNamePrefix=docker --accept-host-key -t debugtags /usr/local/ansible/playbooks/docker.yml
```

Some things to note:

- I've tried this with both -t and --tags.
- Without the -t or --tags, the playbook runs fine and executes all the plays - been using it for weeks

Below, find the files in question and the output

**roles/docker/tasks/main.yml**

```
    - name: check ServerNamePrefix set
      fail: msg="ServerNamePrefix not provided"
      when: ServerNamePrefix is undefined

    - include_tasks: apt_update.yml
      #- include_tasks: timezone.yml
      #- include_tasks: required_software.yml
    - include_tasks: postfix.yml
    - include_tasks: bashrc.yml
    - include_tasks: diskinit.yml
      #- include_tasks: hostfile.yml
    - include_tasks: repositories.yml
    - include_tasks: web_packages.yml
    - include_tasks: configfiles.yml
    - include_tasks: modules.yml
    - include_tasks: groups.yml
    - include_tasks: users.yml
    - include_tasks: directories.yml
    - include_tasks: wkhtmltopdf.yml
    - include_tasks: deploy_env_and_configuration.yml
    - include_tasks: pushwildcardssl.yml
    - include_tasks: touch_files.yml
    - include_tasks: debugtags.yml
```

**roles/docker/tasks/debugtags.yml**

```
- name: debug tags
  debug: 
    msg: debug tags
  tags: 
    - debugtags
```

**output**

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 4a9190122ed4
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "after": "777b48c3f3018bbf5078602209027da6d2b61feb",
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "before": "777b48c3f3018bbf5078602209027da6d2b61feb",
    "changed": false,
    "remote_url_changed": false
}
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 4a9190122ed4

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Ed Greenberg